# Idempotency and Jordan cells

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents, jordan-normal-form

Which Jordan cells $J(\lambda,k)$ are idempotent? And how can I use that to determine the Jordan canonical form of any square idempotent matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. It seems the following.

You can easily calculate the square of a Jordan cell. And when you will do it you will easily found which  Jordan cells are idempotents and which Jordan canonical forms of a square idempotent matrix can be.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Idempotent matrices over a field can only have eigenvalues lying in $\{0,1\}$, and every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable.

To confirm what this suggests, take the block and decompose it into $\lambda I+I'$, where $I'$ denotes the matrix with $1$ on the superdiagonal.

Computing $(\lambda I+I')^2=\lambda I+I'$, you will discover that $\lambda^2=\lambda$, so that $\lambda\in \{0,1\}$. You will also need to notice that $(I')^2$ is zero on the places where $I'$ is nonzero.

Comment: So the Jordan form has eigenvalues along the main diagonal and 1 along the superdiagonal, right? Since the matrix only has 0 and 1 eigenvalues, doesn't that mean that the only Jordan cells which are idempotent are either the 1x1 cells 0 or 1, or a block such as $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @user116084 This $2 \times 2$ block is not a Jordan block, because [such blocks have constant diagonals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix).

Comment: @Vedran Ah, so in this case, the only idempotent Jordan cells would be the 1x1 0 or 1 matrices?

Comment: @user116084 Yes: Jordan blocks bigger than $1\times 1$ do not play well with the $(\lambda I+I')^2=\lambda I+I'$ equation.

Comment: @user116084 A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its Jordan blocks are of order $1$.

Comment: When you say that ${I'}^2$ is zero on the places where I' is nonzero, do you mean that in the jordan form of the idempotent matrix, the super diagonal entries will be 0? Or will there be some entries of 1 and some of 0 like a typical jordan matrix?

Comment: @user116084 What's a good way to write this... let's call an upper triangular matrix a $UD_0$ matrix, a strictly upper triangular matrix a $UD_1$ matrix, and a matrix with another diagonal of zeros a $UD_2$ matrix and so on. The thing is that the product of two $UD_k$ matrices is $UD_{k+1}$. You should see what I mean if you square a few examples.

Comment: @user116084 So you eventually ge tdown to $2\lambda I'+I'^2=I'$, right? And then $I'^2=(1-2\lambda)I'$. This isn't possible because the places where $I'$ and $I'^2$ are nonzero are disjoint.

Comment: Ok, I see, but then what would the form be for any square idempotent matrix?